# question in html_checkboxes loop index in smarty template

Tags: php, smarty

i want know how to get the index of html_checkboxes loop index with smarty for each checkbox ??

http://www.smarty.net/manual/en/language.function.html.checkboxes.php

Comment: other than having the index what is the objective, what is the purpose of getting the index ?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to modify the function to do that. As written it's not designed to give you that information. If you need the index you can implement your check-boxes in a smarty loop:

```
<?php

$smarty->assign('checkboxes', array( 'value1', 'value2','value3','value4' ) );

?>
```

And your smarty code:

```
{ foreach from=$checkboxes item=value name=checkboxloop }
<input type="checkbox" name="whatever_name[{$smarty.foreach.checkboxloop.index}]" value="{$value}" />
{ /foreach }
```

So in that case the index (starting from zero) is access by `{$smarty.foreach.checkboxloop.index}` if you want it starting from 1 it's `{$smarty.foreach.checkboxloop.iteration}`